Is there a method to use base.base in an override method?
This might be bad practice, but I'd still like to know if it's possible.
public class BaseClass
{
  protected virtual void createArrays(int vertexCount)
  {
    // do the actual work
  }
}

public class A : BaseClass
{
  protected override void createArrays(int vertexCount)
  {
       // Do something specific to A
       base.createArrays(vertexCount);
  }
}

public class B : A 
{
  protected override void createArrays(int vertexCount)
  {
    //Do something specific to B, but not to A
    base.base.createArrays(vertexCount); // this is the part that doesn't work, I actually want to call the createArrays from the BaseClass
  }
}

It's probably best to inherit both A and B from BaseClass, but I'd appreciate some insights

Having two layers of inheritance is already somewhat smelly...

Check How to invoke (non virtually) the original implementation of a virtual method?

No, this is not allowed at all.
ECMA-334, the C# spec, says:

12.8.15
At binding-time, base_access expressions of the form base.I and base[E] are evaluated exactly as if they were written ((B)this).I and ((B)this)[E], where B is the base class of the class or struct in which the construct occurs. Thus, base.I and base[E] correspond to this.I and this[E], except this is viewed as an instance of the base class.
Note: Unlike this, base is not an expression in itself. It is a keyword only used in the context of a base_access or a constructor_initializer (§15.11.2). end note


Having said that, a straight reading of ECMA-335, the .NET CLI spec, seems to imply that this would be allowed, by using a call (as opposed to callvirt) instruction on that method, as long as it's done as usual through an instance of the same type:

Partition III Section 3.19
When using the call opcode to call a non-final virtual method on an instance other than a boxed value type, verification checks that the instance reference to the method being called is the result of ldarg.s 0, ldarg 0 or ldarg.0 and the caller's body does not contain starg.s 0, starg 0 or ldarga.s 0, ldarga 0.
[Rationale: This means that non-virtually calling a non-final virtual method is only verifiable in the case where the subclass methods calls one of its superclasses using the same this object reference, where same is easy to verify. This means that an override implementation effectively "hides" the superclass' implementation, and
can assume that the override implementation cannot be bypassed by code outside the class hierarchy.
For non-sealed class hierarchies, malicious code can attempt to extend the class hierarchy in an attempt to bypass a class' override implementation. However, this can only be done on an object of the malicious type, and not of the class with the override, which mitigates much of the security concern. end rationale]

I haven't tried it though, and it's possible that this would be considered non-verifiable code by most verifiers. It should at least work, as it's definitely correct (in the sense the IL will compile).

Warning this is really unusual code but it is possible.
As @Charlieface noded the the c# spec does not allow this.
But you can achieve almost everthing with Reflection.
This is defently code that should not be use in any way shape or form.
using System;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp3;

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new B();
        var test = 1;
        b.CreateArrays(test);
    }
}


public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void CreateArrays(int vertexCount)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BaseClass : createArrays");
        // do the actual work
    }
}

public class A : BaseClass
{
    public override void CreateArrays(int vertexCount)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A : createArrays");
        // Do something specific to A
        base.CreateArrays(vertexCount);
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void CreateArrays(int vertexCount)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B : createArrays");
        //Do something specific to B, but not to A
        var m = typeof(BaseClass).GetMethod(nameof(CreateArrays), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        var dm = new DynamicMethod("", typeof(void), new[] { typeof(BaseClass),typeof(int)}, typeof(BaseClass));
        var il = dm.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, m);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        var baseClassCreateArrays = (Action<BaseClass,int>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<BaseClass, int>));
        
        baseClassCreateArrays.Invoke(this,vertexCount);
    }
}

outputs :
B : createArrays
BaseClass : createArrays

In B.CreateArrays we use refelction to create a runtime methode on BaseClass.
And that methode calls BaseClass.CreateArrays.
By using OpCodes.Call and not OpCodes.Callvirt, we only call BaseClass.CreateArrays and not the virtual methodes.

"This is defently code that should not be use in any way shape or form." - why suggest it, then?

The user asked if it was possible not if it was a good idea.

If somebody asked you if they can shoot themselves in the foot, would you tell them  "yes you can - don't do it" or would you show them how to?

You can also call private functions via reflection even outside the class, so this proves very little.

Thats if you can change baseclass but if baseclass is part of a framework you can not edit that file

@Fildor Your metaphor is a bit off. I didn't ask "should I myself in the foot" but rather "how should I load my gun to shoot myself in the foot", so: "Here is how you load a gun, but please don't shoot yourself" Is a good answer.

Not if you have a spark of responsibility in you. @FrederikSteinmetz and this is coming from someone who actually knows a guy that did shoot himself in the foot. Literally.

this answer is much much cleaner - making use of how Delegate.Invoke is internally implemented making direct calls to the method pointer it gets

@Fildor I still disagree. Providing examples how not to do something can be as teachable as showing how to do it.
